# Prevent Powershell non-terminating error from being returned to PHP

Tags: php, powershell

I have a webpage that allows IT staff to enter information on new hires and it will automatically create the appropriate accounts.  I call a Powershell script via PHP with the following command and only return errors:

```
$psPath = 'c:\\Windows\\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\powershell.exe -version 5';
$psDIR = "d:\\wamp64\\www\\includes\\";
$psScript = "NewHire.ps1";
$runCMD = $psPath. ' -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned '.$psDIR.$psScript;

$createuser = exec($runCMD.' 2>&1>1' , $out);
```

If there are any errors, I am displaying them on the webpage with `var_dump($out);`

There is one section of my new hire script that is throwing a non-terminating error that is being displayed from `var_dump($out);` I am getting the user's AD username by checking to see if it exists first and then trying again if it exists or using that username.

```
$Count = 1

    DO
    {
        $adUsername = "$Firstname" +"$Lastname".Substring(0,$Count)
        $CheckEmail = C:\GAM\gam.exe info user $adUsername
        $CheckUser = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$Name)" 
        If ($CheckUser -eq $Null -and $CheckEmail -eq $Null)
        {
            $adUsername = $adUsername.ToLower()
        }
        Else
        {
            $Count = $Count + 1
        }
    } Until ($CheckUser -eq $Null -and $CheckEmail -eq $Null)
```

What I am trying to do is prevent the error from this section from being logged/displayed.  It shows this everytime from the $out variable:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => string 'Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized' (length=51)
  1 => string 'At D:\wamp64\www\includes\NewHire.ps1:191 char:18' (length=49)
  2 => string '+ ... CheckUser = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$Name)" -ErrorAct ...' (length=79)
  3 => string '+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' (length=75)
  4 => string '    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException' (length=73)
  5 => string '    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirec' (length=78)
  6 => string '   tory.Management.Commands.GetADUser' (length=37)
  7 => string '' (length=0)
```

I have tried using the -ErrorAction Ignore and SilentlyContinue `$CheckUser = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$Name)" -ErrorAction Ignore`, but the error is still being displayed.  Is there anyway I can prevent this or a better way to do this code?

Comment: That error message ("The search filter cannot be recognized") indicates that the filter you've constructed isn't valid. Make sure `$Name` is not `$null`, empty or contains newlines

Comment: Can't believe I missed that...yes instead of $name it should be $adUsername!  Thanks.